# VueJS BackToTop Button

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am experimenting with VueJS but stumbled on something small which I can't seem to find the answer to.

I would like to have a simple BackToTop button and I usually use jQuery to solve this with code like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//ToTop
var totop = $("#totop");
$(window).scroll(function(){
    ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) ? totop.fadeIn() : totop.fadeOut();
});
//Smooth Scroll
$(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    if (location.hash){
        window.scrollTo(0,450);
        target = location.hash.split('#');
        smoothScrollTo($('#'+target[1]));
        }
    },1);
    $('a[href*="#"]').not('[href="#"]').not('[href="#0"]').click(function(event){
        if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname){
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if(target.length){
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top},1000,function(){
                    var $target = $(target);
                    $target.focus();
                    if($target.is(":focus")){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        $target.attr('tabindex','-1');
                        $target.focus();
                    };
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
$(window).bind("mousewheel",function(){$("html,body").stop(true,false);});
//End
});
```

But as I want to completely stick true to VueJS this is for me out of the question.

While I already am using the vue-scrollto library, I find it a bit annoying to use a package for something a simple like this: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-scrollto

My current to top button is coded in html like following:

```
<button id="totop" v-scroll-to="'body'" v-if="toTopVisible"></button>
```

Where as you can see am using the vue-scrolto package and an if statement to make it visible or not on scroll. But even this is something I can't turn my head around how I would this work and activate on scroll after let's say 300px.

What I thought would be something easy, turned out quite hard and while I'm still learning I would love to hear some thoughts regarding this.

What would be a good back to top button VueJS code that not only scrolls back up to 0,0 (or a specific id/hash) but also appears only after 300px and disappears if it's at the top of the page (< than 300px scrolled).

I've already went through countless of Google Pages, CodePens and JSFiddles, but a lot of them either use heavy packages or even combined JQuery with VueJS which in my opinion is even stranger.

So if anyone could enlighten me or give me some direction where I could look for a perfect Back To Top Button that has the simple and similar functionality than my jQuery code has, then that would be great!

Thanks in advance for further information.

Comment: even though you don't like using module, there is already a module for what you are trying to do haha... https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-backtotop

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @JacobGoh, I did came along this one however found that it was just too bloated with too many features than what a simple back to top needs. Hence my question if I could get some pointers or help to getting this back to top button properly written in vue without the need of modules.

If however that package is a better choice than writing it yourself, then I'll probably go with it! Thanks either way for your comment!

Comment: Mind me asking, is that package also available as just a script tag that I can include, other than using NPM and compiling it?

Comment: I am afraid it's not available. sorry for the unsuitable suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the followup, I'll see what I can do with it ;) Much appreciated for your comment!